# Importing data into a new table with different data types (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

I'm trying to import data into a SQL table from an existing table however I continuously get the following error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I've looked around at the other threads on here and have found that converting the column datatypes to 'datetime2' should fix the issue as long as the source date is in this format:

```
01-01-2018 00:00:00 PM     ### mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM
```

My data is in this format and is stored as nchar(255) within the source table:

```
01/01/2018 00:00:00 PM     ### mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM
```

Here is the SQL query I'm using to copy to the table contents:

```
USE [MyDatabase];
GO

set dateformat dmy

INSERT INTO dbo.[Output-Table]
SELECT [FullName]
  ,CAST(REPLACE([LastWriteTime], '/', '-') as datetime2)
  ,CAST(REPLACE([CreationTime], '/', '-') as datetime2)
  ,CAST(REPLACE([LastAccessTime], '/', '-') as datetime2)
  ,[Lenght]
  ,[Extention]
  ,[ID]
  ,[CSVName]
  ,CAST(REPLACE([Date], '/', '-') as datetime2)
  ,[ServerName]
  ,[RunName]
FROM dbo.[Input-Table];
GO
```

My level of SQL expertise isn't the best so any help would be greatly appreciated.

As a next step I'll be passing this through to SQL using PowerShell however this isn't for this post.

Thanks,
J

Comment: If you run the SELECT part alone, do you still get the error?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the syntax and error message

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server hosted in Azure. I'm connecting up to the database using  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Version 14.0.17224.0. When running the SELECT statement values are returned.

Comment: So, what IS the datatype of [LastWriteTime] etc? Is it a string? And which local settings is your Server running on? And last but not least could you please provide some sample data, like TOP 10 of the query you execute for the insert?

Comment: [LastWriteTime] is being stored as nchar(255) i.e. a String within the Input-Table. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

It appears that using the below statement was causing an issue as my date format was in mdy as appose to dmy:

```
set dateformat dmy
```

Should have been:

```
set dateformat mdy
```

Once I made this change my query worked. Here is the final query.

```
USE [MyDatabase];
GO

set dateformat mdy

INSERT INTO dbo.[Output-Table]
SELECT [FullName]
  ,CAST(REPLACE([LastWriteTime], '/', '-') as datetime)
  ,CAST(REPLACE([CreationTime], '/', '-') as datetime)
  ,CAST(REPLACE([LastAccessTime], '/', '-') as datetime)
  ,[Lenght]
  ,[Extention]
  ,[ID]
  ,[CSVName]
  ,[Date]
  ,[ServerName]
  ,[RunName]
FROM dbo.[Input-Table];
GO
```

Additionally you would have seen that the [Date] column has also been changed this was due to the data within the column being in the incorrect format.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following (specify the date conversion format).

```
DECLARE @dateText NCHAR(255) = '25-12-2018 05:00:00 PM'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @dateText, 105) -- 105: dd-mm-yyyy
--Result: 2018-12-25 17:00:00.000

SET @dateText = '12-25-2018 05:00:00 PM'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @dateText, 110) -- 110: mm-dd-yyyy
--Result: 2018-12-25 17:00:00.000
```

Also converting the time `00:00:00 PM` will fail, so should replace the hours for 12 and PM for AM in that case.

```
DECLARE @dateText NCHAR(255) = '25-12-2018 00:00:00 PM'

SELECT
    @dateText,
    UpdatedText = REPLACE(@dateText, '00:00:00 PM', '12:00:00 AM'),
    UpdatedDateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(@dateText, '00:00:00 PM', '12:00:00 AM'), 105)
/*
Results:
    25-12-2018 00:00:00 PM
    25-12-2018 12:00:00 AM
    2018-12-25 00:00:00.000
*/
```